# What are the ways to reduce the time taken by a Select query?

Tags: sql, performance, oracle, jsp, query-optimization

I am creating an API in JSP for my oracle database.

I have two tables containing 20k records each. I need to perform a natural join, the result will be shown in a JSP page in JSON format. My problem is it is taking almost 3mins to load the JSON page.

Please tell me how do I improve the performance in my page?

Comment: good article about how to improve select statements: http://www.componentace.com/help/absdb_manual/increasesqlperformance.htm

Comment: Are you really trying to render 20k records on one page?  (consider using a datagrid with page controls so the page doens't try to render all that data at once.  How long does the Select take to run against the database alone ? ( < 1 sec not much you can do problem is on JSP side, thus data grid & use of pages) if > 1 sec, then we need to see SQL, table structure and results of a query analyzer to help [Others Agree](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10734751/performance-issue-to-load-huge-records-in-a-single-jsp-page)

Comment: @xQbert: In oracle it takes more than 50secs on average.. As it's a JSON page, I can't use datagrid. If there is some way to use datagrid then please tell me.

Comment: @dibya [Binding datagrid & json example](http://www.jqwidgets.com/binding-jquery-grid-to-json-data/) or perhaps [with page control](http://www.jeasyui.com/tutorial/datagrid/datagrid11.php)

Comment: Natural joins are Teh Suck!

Answer (score 3):

To optimize a process (*any process!*) you need to learn where it spends its time. If you spend 10 seconds in the DB and 170 seconds in java you don't want to start with optimizing the query obviously.

The first thing you should do is run the query directly in the database, with the minimum graphical display, for instance in SQL*Plus with:

```
set timing on
set autotrace traceonly statistics
```

This will give you a rough idea of how much time is spent fetching from the database. Most likely for a join of two small tables of 20k rows this should not take more than 1 sec.

Run the query on the DB server to eliminate any network latency.

If it takes more time it means that either the rows are very large (many large columns) or you have an abnormaly large [high water mark](http://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0%3a%3a%3a%3aP11_QUESTION_ID:669044239081).

I assume that Oracle is picking the right plan for the query (which should be a `FULL SCAN + HASH JOIN` since you're not using a WHERE condition).

Answer (score 2):

First of all, you should know that there are consultants who make very fine livings from tuning other people's shonky code.  They couldn't do that if performance optimization was just a matter of a few rules.  The specific details of your case really matter.

So here are a couple of observations.

We have two statements of interest.  In the question body this:

> "My problem is it is taking almost 3mins to load the JSON page."

...and in a comment this:

> " In oracle it takes more than 50secs on average"

Which suggests that most of the time is *not* being spent in the database.  Consequently the first focus of tuning should be either the front end code or the network.  A result set of 20,000 rows - comprising records from two tables - might be a lot of packets.  Perhaps your network/system admin can advise.

One thing to check is that you're collecting *sets* of information from the database, rather than doing it row-by-row (or even worse, attribute-by-attribute).

Even so, 50 secs is a lot of time to get twenty thousand rows in the database, unless the rows are really long.  Or there isn't enough memory to sort a hash join, so it's paging to disk.

---

> " Is 50sec a resonalble time?"

Define *reasonable*.  If I'm a user and I have a customer on a phone and I can't respond to them until this query returns then of course it's completely unacceptable.  But if this is an asynchronous web service which puts a message into a queue when it completes and I can deal with it at any point in the next hour then 50 secs is fine.

As I said already, the specific details of your case matter.  But you haven't provided any details, so generalities are all you can have.  And in general I would say that almost a minute *is* too long to join and select one? two? twenty? whatever rows from two trivially small tables.

But let me repeat myself: fifty seconds is a less than half the total elapsed time you say it takes to populate your page.  Those other other 130 seconds become even more glaring if you're passing back a handful of rows instead of twenty thousand.

Comment: The result set is not 20,000 rows. It is the result of natural join of two tables having 20,000 rows. So 20,000*20,000 comparisons are done to get the resultset. Is 50sec a resonalble time?

Answer (score 1):

Available indexes for conditions from WHERE clause

It is recommended to make sure that optimal indexes for conditions from WHERE clause are available. 
See the topic "Speeding up Searches and Filters" for more details on how to check search conditions and create appropriate indexes. 
For example if you would like to get a better performance for the query:

```
SELECT * FROM customer WHERE City='Kapaa Kauai' AND State='HI'
```

the best way to speed it up is to create the following case-sensitive index:

```
ABSTable1.AddIndex('idxCityState', 'City;State', []);
```

If you need to get a better performance for the query:

```
SELECT * FROM customer WHERE Upper(City)='KAPAA KAUAI'
```

the best way to speed it up is to create the following case-insensitive index:

```
ABSTable1.AddIndex('idxCity_nocase', 'City', [ixCaseInsensitive]);
```

Available indexes for JOIN conditions

To improve a JOIN query, please check that each field from JOIN conditions has an index. 
For example if you would like to improve the performance of the query:

```
SELECT Event_Name,Venue FROM Events e JOIN Venues v ON (e.VenueNo = v.VenueNo)
```

you can create the following indexes:

```
VenuesTable.AddIndex('idxVenueNo', 'VenueNo', [ixPrimary]);  
EventsTable.AddIndex('idxVenueNo', 'VenueNo', []);
```

Rewriting query with OR conditions as a UNION

Absolute DB cannot use indexes to improve performance of a query with OR conditions. You can speedup your 
query

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE (Field1 = 'Value1') OR (Field2 = 'Value2')
```

by creating indexes on each field in the above conditions and by using a UNION operator instead 
of using OR:

```
SELECT ... WHERE Field1 = 'Value1'  
UNION  
SELECT ... WHERE Field2 = 'Value2'
```

Available indexes for ORDER BY clause

If you want to speed up a "live" SELECT from a single table with ORDER BY clause, you can create a compound index for ORDER BY fields. 
For example if you would like to increase the speed of the query:

```
SELECT * FROM Employee ORDER BY LastName, FirstName
```

you can do it by creating the following compound index:

```
ABSTable1.AddIndex('idxLastNameFirstName', 'LastName;FirstName', []);
```

Available indexes for GROUP BY clause

To get a better performance for SELECT from a single table with GROUP BY clause, you can create a compound index for GROUP BY fields. 
For example if you want to speed up the query:

```
SELECT * FROM Employee GROUP BY FirstName
```

you can create the following index:

```
ABSTable1.AddIndex('idxFirstName', 'FirstName', []);
```

Select from in-memory tables

Your query perofrmance could be increased also if you will move all data from disk tables to in-memory tables and you will perform a query using in-memory copies of the disk tables (Set TABSQuery.InMemory property to True before query execution).

SELECT INTO vs INSERT SELECT

In some cases SELECT ... INTO some_table query runs faster than INSERT INTO some_table (SELECT ...), in another cases INSERT INTO is faster. Please note that the RequestLive property could have an impact on a performance of these queries.

Comment: Well I am not using where condition at all..

Comment: There are a lot of ways to improve select statements and they are all in my answer, they are not all containing the where condition.